# How to measure memory usage and efficiency?

Tags: javascript, browser, memory-management

I have a web app that uses a lot of JavaScript and is intended to run non-stop (for days/weeks/months) without a page reload.

However, Chrome is crashing after a few hours. Safari doesn't crash as often, but it does slow down considerably.

How can I check whether or not the issues are with my code, or with the browser itself? And what can I do to resolve these issues?

Answer (score 15):

Using [Chrome Developer Profile Tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/profiles.html) you can get a snapshot of what's using your CPU and get a memory snapshot.

Take 2 snaps shots. Select this first one and switch to comparison as shown below

[image]

The triangle column is the mathmatical symbol delta or change. So if your deltas are positive, you are creating more objects in memory. I'd would then take another snapshot after a given period of time, say 5 minutes. Then compare the results again. Looking at **delta**

If your deltas are constant, you are doing an good job at memory manageemnt. If negative, your code is clean and your used objects are able to be properly collected, again a great job.

If your deltas keep increasing, you probably have a memory leak.

Also,

```
document.getElementsByTagName('*'); // a count of all DOM elements
```

would be useful to see if you are steadily increasing you DOM elements.

Comment: Hmm...yeah, I already started using the "Heap profiler", but couldn't figure out how to read the results.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome also has the "about:memory" page, but I agree with IAbstractDownVoteFactory - developer tools are the way to go!