# How can I find out how much memory is allocated to a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, memory-management, memory-leaks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript object size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248302/javascript-object-size)
>   [How to measure memory usage and efficiency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7473307/how-to-measure-memory-usage-and-efficiency)

I guess the answer is probably "You can't", but is there any way to see how much memory is allocated to each object in the DOM/javascript environment? What tools are there and does it vary from browser to browser?

If the answer is indeed "You can't" can anyone explain why not?

Comment: like that? [JavaScript object size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248302/javascript-object-size)

Answer (score 4):

Using Chrome, you can use their developer tools (CTRL + SHIFT + I or F12).  Click on the Profiles tab and press the eyeball icon in the status bar.

My versions of Safari and IE8 also have profiling tools, but for CPU only, not memory usage.